# Loading 2.0 .NET assembly on 4.0 .NET Runtime

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

All,

Lets say I have an assembly compiled under .NET 2.0. Can I run this assembly on a PC that has on .NET 4.0 without any redirection etc? Just out of the box.

Thanks,
MK

Comment: did you try?
I mean, it shouldn't be a problem if you have all the necessary references

Comment: Yes.  This is easy to test, don't hesitate to try.  And you should to verify that bug fixes in .NET 4 don't byte.  If it is an EXE then a .config file with `<supportedRunTime>` is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the 4.0 framework installs side-by-side with 1.1 and 2.0/3.5, you would need the .Net Framework 2.0 installed in order to run a 2.0 application without modification.

If you would like the application to run using the .Net 4.0 Framework, you should [alter the application configuration to do so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w519wzk.aspx):

```
<configuration>
   <!-- may need useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" -->
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

If you reference .Net Framework 2.0 assemblies from a .Net Framework 4.0 application you may have to update your application's manifest, but usually this is handled in Visual Studio for you.