# .Net Framework 2 application not working on Windows 10

Tags: c#

I got the app.config file in my C# project but Windows 10 x64 still asked me to install .Net to run the compiled app (on a fresh Windows). I thought using this config file would work. What is the way of making a .Net 2.0 app to work out-of-the-box on Windows 10?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Move the 4.0 entry to the first.

Comment: @LexLi Good advice. Apps compiled for 2.0 start and run faster that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get your `app.config` right?

A normal `app.config` would structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>  
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sorry. I copied the code from a different project. The app.config in question did have the <startup> tags. The sku attribute wasn't used though.

Comment: I think I cannot run tests anymore. I have Visual Studio and all the frameworks installed. But, I used your solution, except for the sku attribute, and none of my apps ran.

Comment: I'm gonna add the sku too, next time I install Win10, if I still use .Net 2.0 by then.

Comment: @CoreTm It seems okay to do so, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720839/loading-2-0-net-assembly-on-4-0-net-runtime

Comment: @CoreTm That would be better.